# Store XHR response globally

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron, global-variables, nightmare

I'm using `nightmare` evaluation to intercept the XHR response. I'm currently storing the response in the `window` object. The disadvantage of that is after a navigation or page reload, the stored responses are being truncated.

I want to store them in a global array variable, however, nightmare `evaluate` method is running on some different Javascript context and even though I can access the variable and push the response, while debugging on my renderer process, it says the variable is empty.

**My current code**:

```
Nightmare.evaluate(() => {
    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function (method: string, url: string, async: any, user: string, pass: string) {
        this.addEventListener("readystatechange", () => {
            if (this.readyState === 4) { // State complete...

                window.__responses.push({
                    responseText: this.responseText,
                    readyState: this.readyState,
                    url: url,
                    method: method
                });
            }
        }, false);
    };

    window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open.apply(this, arguments);
})
```

**Question:**

How can I properly store the responses into a global variable, so it will not be truncated on page reload or navigation?